# Working with SELECT and SUB SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL, I have never worked with the select sub and I ended up getting lost with it.

**Meu SQL:**

```
    SELECT CLI.id, CLI.nome, CLI.senha, CLI.email, CLI.cpf, CLI.celular, CLI.data_nasc, CLI.genero, CLI.data_cadastro, CLI.status, CLI.id_socket, ATEN.mensagem, ARQ.nome AS foto, ATEN.data_mensagem
FROM ut_clientes AS CLI
LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ ON (ARQ.id_tipo = CLI.id AND ARQ.tipo = "ut_clientes")
INNER JOIN ut_atendimentos AS ATEN ON (ATEN.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id)
WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_envio != 59163 
GROUP BY CLI.id 
ORDER BY ATEN.data_mensagem
DESC
```

Well, what I would like to do is group the messages according to the customer ID and bring only the last message recorded in the database according to the data_mensagem.

I have tried in many ways but always the last one that is displayed is the first message inserted in DB.

If anyone can help me, I'll be grateful. Thank you guys!

Comment: Please post in English, or post this to [Portuguese site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...  I am using a join to a pre-query (PQ alias).  This query just goes to your messages and grabs the client ID and the most recent based on the MAX().  By doing the group by here, it will at most return 1 record per client.  I also have the WHERE clause to exclude the one ID you listed.

From THAT result, you do a simple join to the rest of your query.

```
SELECT 
      CLI.id, 
      CLI.nome, 
      CLI.senha, 
      CLI.email, 
      CLI.cpf, 
      CLI.celular, 
      CLI.data_nasc, 
      CLI.genero, 
      CLI.data_cadastro, 
      CLI.status, 
      CLI.id_socket, 
      ATEN.mensagem, 
      ARQ.nome AS foto, 
      PQ.data_mensagem
   FROM 
      ut_clientes AS CLI
         LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ 
            ON CLI.id = ARQ.id_tipo 
            AND ARQ.tipo = "ut_clientes"
         INNER JOIN
         ( select 
                 ATEN.id_usuario_envio,
                 MAX( ATEN.data_mensagem ) as MostRecentMsg
              from 
                 ut_atendimentos AS ATEN
              where
                 ATEN.id_usuario_envio != 59163 
              group by
                  ATEN.id_usuario_envio ) PQ
           ON CLI.id = PQ.id_usuario_envio
   GROUP BY 
      CLI.id 
   ORDER BY 
      PQ.data_mensagem DESC
```